# SQL - Update multiple rows at once with values from multiple other rows in the same table

Tags: sql

I apologize in advance if this was asked already, I tried searching but couldn't find an exact match.

Basically, I have a table that contains themes. Use the snippet below as a rough idea of how the table is set up.

```
theme_name  field_name  color  
'Default'   'Header'    'Orange' 
'Default'   'Footer'    'Orange'
'Default'   'Body'      'Orange'
'Newtheme   'Header'    'Red' 
'Newtheme'  'Footer'    'White'
'Newtheme'  'Body'      'Blue'
```

Basically, what I need to do is write a query that updates the values in the "color" field for each row of theme_name default to match those of the corresponding values on the rows for Newtheme. In other words, it should look like this at the end:

```
theme_name  field_name  color  
'Default'   'Header'    'Red' 
'Default'   'Footer'    'White'
'Default'   'Body'      'Blue'
'Newtheme   'Header'    'Red' 
'Newtheme'  'Footer'    'White'
'Newtheme'  'Body'      'Blue'
```

Unfortunately, there is no unified ID number on the table for every row with the same theme_name, and I am unable to create one.

Now, each theme has a lot more rows in the real table than the example I gave. I could write use

```
SET value=(Select value 
           from Table 
           where theme_Name='Newtheme') 
where theme_name='Default' 
  and field_name='Header'`
```

That would fix a single row. Then I could repeat that update statement for each and every row. However, I suspect there's a much quicker way to do this, where I could update all of them in one single update statement. I just have no idea what it is.

Hopefully, my request makes sense. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple co-related UPDATE query:

```
update the_table
  set color = (select color
               from the_table t2
               where t2.theme_name = 'NewTheme'
                 and t2.field_name = the_table.field_name)
where theme_name = 'Default';
```

This would fail if `(theme_name, field_name)` is not unique however

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-join to do this. Try the following:

```
update a
set a.color = b.color
from themes a
join themes b on a.field_name = b.field_name and a.them_name <> b.theme_name
where a.theme_name = 'Default'
```